# Covariance of random variables with different support

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I was wondering I have two probability mass function of two random variables like this :

$$ p_z(z) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        \frac{1}{4} & \mbox{if } z = 0 \\
        \frac{1}{2}& \mbox{if } z = 1 \\
        \frac{1}{4}& \mbox{if } z = 2
    \end{array}
\right.$$
$$ p_w(w) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        \frac{1}{2} & \mbox{if } w = 0 \\
        \frac{1}{2}& \mbox{if } w = 1 \\
    \end{array}
\right.$$

**If I want to compute E(WZ)**, how do I proceed since the two variables don't have the same support ?
Should I create a joint distribution ?

Comment: I guess "si" means "if"?

Comment: I have edited the question, I copied some part of the latex from internet and did not change it... I don't know if I can create a joint distribution from two separate pmfs and how to do this

Comment: Notice that the variables are independent, so $E(WZ)=E(W)E(Z)$

Comment: Actually they are not, I change that too (Im sorry). In the exercise, there were different random variables that were independent and I create W and Z based on them

Comment: If they are not independent, it is impossible to compute the mean. You need the their conditional probability

Comment: The pmf of (W,Z) right ?

Comment: Yes, that would also be enough

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116671/discussion-between-machinelearner75-and-exodd).

Comment: Don't worry about support.  You can always add a $p=0$ at the points where it hasn't been defined.